# How do I recover a UV map I used to make an image mask?

Tags: uv

I have an object with two UV Maps.  I had made an image mask for one the UV Maps that I want to edit but I can't recover the UV Map without doing the unwrapping again which I don't fully remember which faces I included.

I always feel like I make a UV Map and they just disappear and exist in some magical land.  They function but I can't see them or edit them.

I want to recover "rust.map" UV Map and edit the image here over that UV map.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you cant "recover" a UV layer, either it is in the list or it is gone, there's no recycle bin. If you din't close Blender yet you might still be able to undo until it is back, if there's enough steps left., though you will lose everything else. Also try the backup or auto save files.

Comment: I didn't delete the uv map.  It is in the list as you can see in the image.  I just want to bring back up on the screen in the uv image editor.

Comment: Do you have selection syncing turned on? Have you selected all faces in the 3D view?